# getting Value.Animator class not found error in android

Tags: android, animation

I have used animation in my activity. Code works fine on 4.0+ android device as well emulator but while running on below 4.0 giving class not found error.
Please find below logs which I'm getting:-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.animation.ValueAnimator
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.sharekhanmerge.Main.slideAnimator(Main.java:296)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.sharekhanmerge.Main.access$0(Main.java:294)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.sharekhanmerge.Main$2.onPreDraw(Main.java:84)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:571)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1254)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-19 10:53:31.804: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: as you read in the docs it was added in API level 11 Android 3.0.x HONEYCOMB

Comment: @pskink can it be supported by any library? or any alternative way to support animation.

Comment: where do you need it (API level)?

Comment: I need it in API level-9, can you please help me if you know any supporting lib for same?? @pskink

Comment: It Worked @pskink. Thanks :) but issue i have came across while using in api level 9 is in case of using  animate method will be giving error as its available in level 12 on wards.

Comment: Its solved. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue I managed to resolved it by adding the following line in to ur app level gradle

```
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
```